# How to create horizontal line at bottom or above in a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to create a horizontal line like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Checking that Wordpress theme out on http://themeforest.net the exact CSS is:

```
border-bottom: 5px solid #F88C00;
```

You may obviously want to apply your own color and thickness to the line.

In the example this has been applied to the `<nav>` element of the page but would obviously work equally well on whatever other element you chose to add it to.

Answer (score 2):

use css.
`border-bottom: solid 3px orange;`